# When and to which directory should I set HBASE_CLASSPATH property in hbase-env.sh?

Tags: hadoop, classpath, hbase, configure

I am setting the  configurations in `hbase-env.sh` for setting up hbase in pseudo-distributed mode by following some tutorials from some blogs, I wonder why some people have recommended setting the `HBASE_CLASSPATH` property in `hbase-env.sh` while others do not, also I am confused what path should I give it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HBASE_CLASSPATH should be the path of jars you wish to use with your HBase. For example, if you have written a custom HBase filter then in order to make it available and use it in your app you need to uncomment and edit HBASE_CLASSPATH in the hbase-env.sh to point it at the jar containing the filter.

IMHO, if you are going to use only the classes provided by HBase then you should not face any difficulty if you do not set this property, provided your HBase setups is proper.